# Placement of "here" with "Am I the only one...?"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, word-order, sentence-choice

Are these sentences correct?

> - 1) **"Am I the only one who doesn't play video games here?"**
> - 2) **"Here, am I the only one who doesn't play video games?"**

Can I say these two sentences to mean **"Am I the only one here who doesn't play video games?"** I'm asking this because especially the sentence number 1 sounds kind of wrong to me. It sounds as if I'm talking about playing video games at the place we're at while it's not what I mean.

*Context:* Let's say I'm in a friend group. Everybody's talking about video games and I want to ask if I'm the only one among us who doesn't play video games.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I would not be the only one to say both are right.

In speech, people often pre-position it.

The **here** should be understood in the context of a speech act (Austin).

In fact, it can go in one of three places:

> "Here, am I the only one who doesn't play video games?"
>       "Am I the
>   only one here who doesn't play video games?"
>
> "Am I the only one who doesn't play video games here?"

Though one might be less common, all three are heard in actual speech.

Pre-positioned, post positioned and after the relevant noun.

In fact, the word here can refer to a situation about which we are those commenting on this know nothing, really.

Answer (score 1):

The word *here* can be ambiguous in a sentence like this, and the best way to solve your problem is not to move it, but to replace it:

> Am I the only one **in this group** who doesn't play video games?